# Collections in Create.js

Tags: create.js

According to Create.js' [integration guide](http://createjs.org/guide/), it should be possible to create editable collections of blocks.

> Relationships between entities allow you to communicate structured
>   content to Create.js, which will turn them into Backbone collections.
>   For example, to annotate a list of blog posts:

```
<div about="http://example.net/blog/" rel="dcTerms:hasPart">
  <div about="http://example.net/my-post">...</div>
  <div about="http://example.net/second-post">...</div>
</div>
```

This `dcTerms:hasPart` doesn't seem to be present explicitly in Create.js; it's probably from a vocabulary. How can one show to Create.js that this content is a collection and make it show the "Add" button? In my case, I simply have sections which contain `<h2>`, `<h3>` and `<article>`s.

EDIT: Using `rel="hasPart"` in my `<section>`, the button appears. Problem is Create always uses the first element as a template. In this case, it uses my `<h2>` as template, which is not what I intended. So my question now would be how to trigger the "add" event in my section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hackish solution:

Using javascript, I created a new section or article in the DOM, then restarted Create calling `$('body').midgardCreate({...})` again. Create will now recognize the new block. When I edit some fields in the block, the "Save" button is enabled and I can submit the new block.